# How to copy a object to an existing object in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two object A and B with same type, and want to copy all object A's field to object B but keep object B's PK.

A well known method is change object A's pk to None and save, it will create a new object with object A's field, but what I want is to copy to an existing object not create a new object.

Comment: It depends on what A contains.  If it's simple enough you can use the `copy` module, but it's difficult to suggest anything without some more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the PK and save.

```
objA.pk = objB.pk
objA.save()
```